# Vector holding (certain) (sub)classes (instead of instances of)

Tags: actionscript-3

So I've only somewhat recently I've started ActionScript 3.

For practice purposes I'm trying to make a simple game that should have a small number of levels. All levels are a subclass of the super class World.

So, basically I would want to do something like:

```
private static var levels:Vector.<Class> = new <Class>[ Level1, Level2 ];
```

Except in this case I only know that the classes in my vector are a subclass of Class (right?), where as I would like to know they are sub classes of World.

I know I can grab the Class from the vector, then cast to World- but if at all possible I really would prefer to be able to do this without such casting.

Comment: You don't get any benefit from using Vector if you type it to class. What's wrong with this - private static var levels:Vector.<World> = new <World>[Level1, Level2];

Comment: Level1 and Level2 are the names of the classes that extend the World class. They're not instances of/objects. If I did <World> I could only place instances of world in there, not subclasses of it.

Comment: Understood. Probably nothing to be gained from using a Vector in this case as you won't really get any of the benefits of the construct, ie. type safety (you could stick any class on it) or optimisation. If you can't stick instances on it (and I can understand why you might not want to do that in this case), you might consider looking at a factory pattern which strikes me as the right pattern for this case.

Comment: Going to have a look at the factory pattern, thanks!